# Why does append only work once?

Tags: jquery, button, append

I am making a price list that adds a line every time the 'next' button is pressed. I am trying to append the individual price after each line. However it only works for the first two lines, but printing the amount of lines ('totalCabs'), at the end, works fine.

here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var i = 2;
var totalPrice = 0;
var insert = $('<p class="nom">' +
    '<select id="cab' + i + '">' +
    '<option value="b1">B1</option>' +
    '<option value="b2">B2</option>' +
    '<option value="b3">B3</option>' +
    '<option value="bnd">Base No Drawer</option>' +
    '<option value="bt">Base Trey</option>' +
    '<option value="d3">D3</option>' +
    '<option value="d4">D4</option>' +
    '<option value="sc">SC</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '<input id="cab' + i + 'Size" type="text" />' +
    '<div id="p' + i + '"></div>' +
    '</p>');

$("body").on('click', 'button', (function() {
    $("#poo").append(insert.clone());
    var cabP = '#p' + (i - 1);
    printPrice(cabP);
    i ++;
    document.getElementById('totalCabs').innerHTML = i-1;
}));
function printPrice(place){
    var ap = " $111";
    $(place).append(ap);
}
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="poo">
    <p class="nom">
        <select id="cab1">
            <option value="b1">B1</option>
            <option value="b2">B2</option>
            <option value="b3">B3</option>
            <option value="bnd">Base No Drawer</option>
            <option value="bt">Base Trey</option>
            <option value="d3">D3</option>
            <option value="d4">D4</option>
            <option value="sc">SC</option>
        </select>
        <input id="cab1Size" type="text" />
        <div id="p1"></div>
    </p>
</div>
<button id="btn1">Next</button>
<div id="cabEnter"></div>
<div id="cabPercentage"></div>
<div id="totalCabs"></div>
<div id="totalCabs2"></div>
<div id="subtotalPrice"></div>
<div id="totalPrice"></div>
```

Comment: Initial fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcq7d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hcq7d/2/

The problem is that the variable `insert` gets created when `i = 2`. Although you change the value of `i` afterwards, this change doesn't affect the value of `insert` since it has already been created. So, rather than just cloning the `insert` jQuery object, actually create a new one, passing in the new value of i:

```
function getInsert(i){
    return $('<p class="nom">' +
            '<select id="cab' + i + '">' +
            '<option value="b1">B1</option>' +
            '<option value="b2">B2</option>' +
            '<option value="b3">B3</option>' +
            '<option value="bnd">Base No Drawer</option>' +
            '<option value="bt">Base Trey</option>' +
            '<option value="d3">D3</option>' +
            '<option value="d4">D4</option>' +
            '<option value="sc">SC</option>' +
            '</select>' +
            '<input id="cab' + i + 'Size" type="text" />' +
            '<div id="p' + i + '"></div>' +
            '</p>');
}
```

And then, within the `click` handler:

```
$("#poo").append(getInsert(i));
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks. I was under the assumption that when 'insert' was called again it would use the incremented 'i'.